# HTTP Client with Unity, application hangs

Tags: c#, http

I have a pretty basic script in my Unity game which is trying to submit form data in POST to a server. But unity seems to freeze/hang indefinitely. I am confused why this is happening and so i don't know how to solve the problem.

I made my code loosely following this article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient#making-web-requests

My server does receive the request and does write one back. But because unity is frozen its not really usable at the moment.

My class looks like this:

```
public class HTTPManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private void Awake()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
        ProcessRepositories().Wait();
    }

    private async Task ProcessRepositories()
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("u", "test")
        });

        //this goes to http://localhost:8080/hello with POST u=test
        HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync("hello",content);

        Debug.Log("Is Success: "+result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        Debug.Log("Status code: "+result.StatusCode);
        Debug.Log("Reason Phrase: "+result.ReasonPhrase);
        Debug.Log("Headers: "+result.Headers);
        Debug.Log("Content: "+result.Content);
        Debug.Log("Request Message: "+result.RequestMessage);
        Debug.Log("Version: "+result.Version);

    }
}
```

Whats causing the hanging issue??

Comment: Don't use HttpClient with unity, use the class [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html), you can use it in a coroutine and yield return it and it will wait for the download to complete.

Comment: Whats different to coroutines and async stuff?

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/coroutine-vs-async-method.483746/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ProcessRepositories().Wait();
```

is blocking on `async` code and it is causing a deadlock. Stephen Clearly has a whole series of posts on [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Either make all the code `async` all the way up or schedule continuations on your `Task`.

EDIT: It seems that `Awake` is a `Unity` method. For this you have 4 options:

1) Remove `async Task` from `ProcessRepositories()`. Remove the `await` in the method body and make your calls to your server synchronous. This will cause jitters and it not a recommended solution in a game environment.

2) Remove `.Wait()` from `ProcessRepositories()`. This will cause your code to async post to server but you won't be able to do anything with the the response. This is fine if you don't care about the response.

3.) If you do care about the response, you can schedule `Continuations` on `ProcessRepositories()`. This is a type of "callback" that will run when your `Task` has `RanToCompletion` or it errored out. To achieve this, change `ProcessRepositories()` to `ProcessRepositories().ContinueWith(task=>
{
// in here you can access task.Result to get your response
})` and change your `ProcessRepositories` method to return the `HttpResponseMessage` `result` 
i.e `return await client.PostAsync("hello",content);`

4) Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` as mentioned below but that will return the result on a different context and seeing that this Unity, you probably want the result on the UI thread, so just watch out for that.

Comment: Ah damn, the article had .Wait() then when i removed it VS gave me some kind of warning so i assumed i had to have it. Thanks for that :) By the way do you know how to get the text of the result from the webserver, i thought result.Content did it but that gave `Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent` which isn't quite right.

Comment: You can try `await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: Hmm wait where does that go ? As a seperate thing to my PostAsync? EDIT: ah works :) thanks

Comment: Just below `HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync("hello",content);`. So do: `string content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); Debug.Log("Content: "+content);`

Comment: But his Awake() method is't async, so it will never wait for the completion.

Comment: @john I think he changed it, otherwise his deadlock won't be fixed

Comment: I haven't changed the behaviour of `awake` it calls auto when the game runs. Its a built in unity method. What issue might i still get?

Comment: How is `Awake` a `Unity` method, it is `private`?

Comment: When your game starts it auto calls Awake which is where you initialise things.Its part of their execution order. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html

I don't know how it has access to it when its private but i guess that comes from a lower level aspect in c++.

Comment: @john could you elaborate on your comment ? Is my code still wrong?

Comment: @Sir If you can't change the signature of  `Awake` to `async Task Awake()` then you either have to `synchronously` `post` to your server of have a `fire and forget`, which is what you currently have without `.Wait()`. This means your code will `async` post to your server but you won't be able to do anything with the `result`

Comment: @JohanP oh hmm not sure how i would write the code now, i can make a class outside of monobehaviour so dont need to use unity methods but i still need to communicate back to them get the content just not sure how.

Comment: That's not _entirely_ accurate. You can also look at `.ConfigureAwait(false)` if you don't mind the fact that it will return in a different context.

Comment: What do you mean by different context, im getting more confused now lol

Comment: He means if you do `.ConfigureAwait(false)`  any code after the await will not be on the unity main thread so you can not interact with any Unity library functions after the await, however you can still use unity functions in the caller so long as you did not do `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on the function that called `var result = await ProcessRepositories()` you would then modify ProcessRepositories to return a `Task<SomeResultClass>` instead of just a `Task` and pass your values back that way. If you do this you will need to make Awake `asnyc void`.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use HttpClient with unity, use the class [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) and unity's built in coroutine features, yield return it and it will wait for the download to complete.

```
public class HTTPManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IEnumerator Awake()
    {
        return ProcessRepositories();
    }

    private IEnumerator ProcessRepositories()
    {
        var form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("u", "test");
        var www = new WWW("http://localhost:8080/hello", form);
        yield return www;

        Debug.Log("responseHeaders: "+www.responseHeaders);
        Debug.Log("text: "+www.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is unity docs says nothing about how to use HTTPS certificates i presume their setup doesn't support it ?

Comment: Are you using client certificates (if you don't know what that means then the answer is no), if you are not you just type https:// and certificates work fine.

Comment: My plan is to use client certificate on HTTPS eventually yes. For login/register.

Comment: if that is the case then use what Johan recommended in his option 2, just remove the .Wait() and let the code just fire and forget. If you want to get rid of the compiler warning about not doing anything with the task just set it to a temporary throw away variable `var _ = ProcessRepositories();`